# Can't load an image using file picker as asset image in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
  class RoundedImageFile extends StatelessWidget {
  final PlatformFile image;
  final double size;

  const RoundedImageFile({required this.image, required this.size, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: size,
      width: size,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(image.path!),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(size)),
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please add the code correctly

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://youtu.be/LlO5jydXws0

might this can help

you cannot open an file in an asset image if you only want  to open an image through galley use an image piker after saving the image use Image.file(filename)

let me know if i got you correct the question does not have enough in
formation to solve